# How do I build a Windows GUI Application in Eclipse using C++ (a non console application)

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse-cdt

I can't seem to figure out how build a windows GUI application in Eclipse with C++ . I can only build to a console. When I create a new project it doesn't give me the option for a Windows Application. I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++. Am I downloading the wrong flavor of Eclipse? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try googling "building a C++ windows application with Eclipse"?

Comment: Have you searched it on google? Where are you stucked with? What have you tried? You should add this information to your question. Probably eclipse is not linked to a C++ compiler.

Comment: I've been at this task on an off for a month sometimes spending hours at a time in one sitting trying to figure this out. I got it to display the hello world, but I was looking for a way to have a wizard .

Comment: @Paul Griffiths - the  first result in Google is this question. I am sure people come to this website for a reason, and we can't just tell them to go "Google it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Visual Studio, Eclipse CDT does not have a built-in wizard or options for automatically configuring compiler settings and libraries for building Windows GUI applications.  You will need to know what you are doing.  Do you intend to build the GUI using Win32/[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), or perhaps using some other GUI library, like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)?  There are many options.

If you are new to C++ and/or GUI development on windows, then there are easier options to get started with.

Comment: I'm using MinGW and must say thankyou for directing me to Qt Project and WxWidgets. I was reading a some on their sites and am unsure how to use them without spending a great deal of time reading. Do they intergrate into Eclipse or Visual Studio. And yes I am new to C++.

Comment: You should spend some time learning C++ without trying to also learn how to program a GUI at the same time. However, if you are intent on trying to build a GUI from the start using C++, then I suggest downloading the Qt Creator IDE and working through their tutorials, instead of trying to use Eclipse CDT. http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator & http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-tutorials.html

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it. Getting started is sometimes the hardest.Thanks Again !

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example to get you started with creating a simple window:
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html

compiled with mingw this will open a console + the created window.
To hide the console, just add this linker flag: -mwindows

Comment: In the back of my mind I was quietly thinking about such a thing you posted but wasn't going to ask it because i was so focused on a type of wizard setup for an application. Thanks for the extra help !